# Chebyshev's bias limit doesn't exist, but what about the lim sup and lim inf?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias) that there is a bias towards primes being 3 mod 4 v.s. 1 mod 4, but that the primes 3 mod 4 aren't in the lead 100% of the time (more primes up to 26861 are 1 mod 4, the first time they get ahead); in fact, it's been proved the fraction of the time primes mod 3 are ahead does not tend to any limit (though see the earlier link that they do have a logarithmic density of about .9959)

Is it known what the lim sup and lim inf of the fraction of time primes mod 3 are in the lead is? If the lim inf is greater than 1/2, that'd be a strong result in this direction. I'm also interested in any conjectures or heuristics that are relevant here if the answer is not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others agree with you that this is a very interesting question! In [his 1995 paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/anly.1995.15.2.159/html), Jerzy Kaczorowski proves the following facts about these upper and lower (natural) densities, assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis for the modulus $q=4$:

Let $S_{1,3} = \{ m\in\Bbb N\colon \pi(m;4,1) > \pi(m;4,3) \}$ and $S_{3,1} = \{ m\in\Bbb N\colon \pi(m;4,3) > \pi(m;4,1) \}$. Then:

- The lower density of $S_{1,3}$ is $\le0.0000106\dots$, and the upper density of $S_{1,3}$ is $\ge 0.040540454\dots$;
- The lower density of $S_{3,1}$ is $\le 0.9594595$, and the upper density of $S_{3,1}$ is $\ge 0.999989360$.

I believe this is still the state of the art; in particular, I don't believe it's known (even conditionally) that the lower density of $S_{3,1}$ is $\ge\frac12$.

Comment: Cool! Do you know if we should "expect" the upper density to be > 1/2, or is there no real heuristic that applies here and there's no natural guess?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. We could start by looking at some simple functions like $f(x) = 2 + \sqrt2\sin(\sqrt2\log x) + \sin(\log x)$, which is a toy model of the normalized explicit formula for $\pi(x;4,3)-\pi(x;4,1)$; the set of $x$ for which $f(x)>0$ has a well-defined logarithmic density (a bit less than $0.959$), but its natural upper and lower density will be rather different—*how* different is the question.